# How to describe the following that I want, naturally?

Tags: word-request, idiomatic-language

What's the correct way to describe cutting a hose but not completely but half (=the hose is 50% cut off)?

Is it natural to say:

> I cut the hose halfway?

I'm looking for a way to describe what I want, naturally.

Comment: Do you mean that you made a cut across the hose (at right angles to its length), but only halfway through? If so, then "halfway through" may be the phrase you want.

Answer (score 1):

"I cut the hose halfway" could mean you didn't cut it completely through. Therefore, the meaning isn't clear. "I cut off half of the hose" is what, I think, you want.

Comment: Thank you. And how you describe it?  "Now it's cut off half"?